# why subView from another view controller moves as I scroll?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I have a subview from another view controller, whenever my scroll arrives on it, the subview change it's position to x = 0 and y = 0, below my navigation bar, but if I scroll fast and not stop on that view, everything is fine.

the code I use for addSubView is :

```
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "saleView") as! SaleViewController
    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0 , width: saleTopView.frame.width, height: saleTopView.frame.size.height)
    saleTopView.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
```

what I miss? thanks

Answer (score 0):

add

```
popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController : self)
```

at the end. Not a must do, but for simplicity, you could also rewrite

```
popOverVC.view.frame = self.saleTopView.frame
```

Comment: still the same, when scrollview arrives on it, it moves :(

Comment: is saleTopView a popOver itself? try replacing self with saleTopView inside `popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self.saleTopView` .